# copy files by date to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I want to be able to create a batch files that copies files by date only up to 3 or 4 days but use the `%edate%` `%user%\` syntax instead of specifying a date. Here is what I have so far:

```
 XCOPY %user%\folder_1 %edate% %user%\folder_2.
```

I am unable to download any 3 party software.  I can only use the .bat format.

Comment: If you're using an operating system more recent than XP, you can use `forfiles`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment suggestion to use `forfiles` is a good one, but I note the question has remained open. Perhaps more details are required.

If the questioner has a system more recent than XP (and I assume so, as XP and previous are now deprecated) the ROBOCOPY also has appropriate options. I'll give examples of both for files greater than 4 days old.

Using `forfiles`:

```
FORFILES -P %user%\folder_1 /D - 4 /C "CMD /C XCOPY @file %user\folder_2"
```

Using ROBOCOPY:

```
ROBOCOPY %user%\folder_1 %user%\folder_2 /MINAGE:4
```

I hope that is sufficient detail....